# Why do the y-intercept differs between Excel's LINEST function and NumPy's np.linalg.lstsq?

Tags: linear-regression

I'm trying to replicate an excel model in python, and I've used the excel linest formulae to find the y-intercept. Formulae is `INDEX(LINEST(known y's, known x's, True),2)`.

Known `y`'s  `[Highs]= 79.375, 89.5625, 91.5, 75.125, 72.6875, 70.5, 72.625, 70, 68, 67.1875, 68.625, 65.1875`
Known `x`'s `= 1, 2, 3,.. 11, 12`

The below code is trying to replicate the y-intercept but I'm getting different outputs.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
drange = 12
A = np.vstack([ np.arange(drange), np.ones(len(x))]).T
df['intercept'] = df['High'].rolling(drange).apply(lambda y: np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)[0][1], raw=False)
```

In Excel I get `86.82996` for the intercept, in Python I get `84.89503`. I'm trying to get the same Excel result in python.

Comment: Numpy.polyfit is giving 86.83996 from "np.polyfit(x, y, 1)" - this appears strangely similar to the Excel value, unexpectedly off by one of the digits.

Comment: Thanks James. I'm trying it incorporate np.polyfit into the rolling code above, but I get a TypeError message saying 'expected 1D vector for x'